# Why can const char* const & = "hello" compile?

Tags: c++, reference, constants, language-lawyer

I am reading a code snippet from a book and find this:

```
const char* const & a = "hello"; //can compile 
const char*& a = "hello"; //cannot
```

All I know is that when initializing a reference, the *array to pointer conversion* would not take place.

`const char* const &`, a reference to a `const pointer`, the pointer points to `const char`.

`const char*&`, a reference to a `pointer`, the pointer points to 
`const char`.

So why does adding an extra `const`, indicating that the pointer is a `const`, allow it to compile?

Comment: "when initializing a reference, the array to pointer conversion would not take place". This is not exactly correct. When initialising a *reference to an array*, the array to pointer conversion would not take place. There is no such rule for initialising a reference to a pointer.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It's essentially adhering to this formula

```
T const & a = something_convertible_to_T;
```

Where T is `const char*`. In the first case, a temporary pointer can be materialized, assigned the address of the literal, and then have itself bound to the reference. In the second case, since the lvalue reference isn't const, it can't happen. Another example of more of the same

```
const char* && a = "hello"; // rvalue ref makes a no into a yes.
```

Now the temporary pointer is bound to an rvalue reference.

Comment: Yes I get it know. It's the same reason as for `const int& a = 3; //yes`, `int&a = 3; //no`. The *formula* is very helpful. Thanks. It merely becomes harder to recognize that when comes to pointer.

Comment: @SkepticalEmpiricist - It is. What's important to consider when taking in that comment is that the identity conversion also counts (though it's obviously not a very interesting case). `const int& a = 3;` materializes a temporary from a literal int prvalue, and binds a reference to it.

Comment: @StoryTeller I still cannot fully follow, I thought I know what the *identity conversion* means in The Standard but I cannot put it into use trying to understand what you're saying. Can I kindly ask you to elaborate on this?

Comment: @SkepticalEmpiricist - I wasn't trying to be as exact as the standard is on this, but my line of thought (and explanation) tries to follow the C++17 changes to prvalues, the [temporary materialization conversion](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv.rval) and [this bit about initializing references](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.ref#5.2).

Comment: @SkepticalEmpiricist - It's simpler than that. The temporary *can* be materialized in *all* the examples. It's just that the whole of [\[dcl.init.ref\]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.ref#5) doesn't define the meaning of such an initialization. So the program is ill-formed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178836/discussion-between-skepticalempiricist-and-storyteller).

Comment: Didn't expect you guys talk in such details. For me, I am simply enlightened by the *formula* and then see `const char*` as `T`, then I just understand and let it go.. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Rick I appreciate it, just couldn't ignore the fact that by this phrasing alone, both lines have `T` of `const char*`, and so how come they differ? They both materialize to a temporary pointer, and both take the address of the literal. So what was enabling the the reference to bind on one line but preventing on the other? The problem, I gathered, was in the details. And I just didn't see it. Sorry for being tedious about this...

Comment: BTW, using this fruitful formula, you can see why `char* const& a = "hello";` compiles too without error! : ) *ISO C++118 Warning* aside, this is valid code.

Comment: @SkepticalEmpiricist - It's not valid code language-lawyer-wise. The ISO warning should really be an error. An implicit conversion sequence may not discard cv-qualifiers. The compiler accepting it is purely trying not to break code that is stuck in the dark ages.

Comment: Ok if so then I'll re-edit my answer, but just to make sure, you're saying the fact that the string literal itself is an lvalue has nothing to do with the cv-qualieres here?

Comment: @SkepticalEmpiricist - Yes. The string literal is an lvalue of type `const char[6]`. It can only be converted to a `const char*`, not a `char*`.

Answer (score 8):

Some additional phrasing for the bored, after reading the superb answer by @StoryTeller, as I had to go through a different thought process about this.

So syntactically, In both lines we define a *reference* `a`, and in both we shall have a [*materialization* of a *temporary pointer*](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary) that takes the address of the *string literal*. **The only difference** between the two is the 2nd `const` appearing only here:

```
const char* const & a = "hello";
```

and not here:

```
const char*& a = "hello";
```

This 2nd `const` denotes that the object *being referenced* here, [a pointer in this case, is itself const](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.decl#dcl.ptr-2), as in it cannot be modified using this reference.

Hence, because the *type* of this *string literal* is `const char[6]` (and not `const char *` for example), our `lvalue` reference to type `const char*` in the second line cannot bind to it -- but the reference in the first line, being a reference to type `const char* const` could. Why? Because of the [rules of *reference initialization*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#5):

> (5) A reference to type “cv1 T1” is initialized by an expression of type “cv2 T2” as follows:
>
> - (5.1) If the reference is an lvalue reference and the initializer expression
>
>   - (5.1.1) is an lvalue (but is not a bit-field), and “cv1 T1” is reference-compatible with “cv2 T2”, [...]
>   - (5.1.2) has a class type (i.e., T2 is a class type) [...]

Both the expressions are *lvalue*s, but **our “cv1 T1” is not [*reference-compatible*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#4.sentence-2)** with our “cv2 T2” and “T2” is not a class type.

> - (5.2) Otherwise, if the reference is an **lvalue reference to a type that is not const-qualified** or is volatile-qualified, **the program is ill-formed**

The reference is indeed *not* const-qualified: our “T1” is `const char*`, which is a *pointer to const* , as opposed to a *const pointer*. The actual type here is a pointer type, so this is what matters.

The Clang error for the second line, read with that in mind, tells us exactly this:

```
error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'const char *' cannot bind to a value of unrelated type 'const char [6]'
    const char*& a = "hello";
                 ^    ~~~~~~~
```

The part about being *non-const lvalue reference* is exactly ¶5.2 -- the *lvalue* in our case is a pointer to `const`, but itself isn't const! Unlike the first line. The part about binding to an *unrelated type* is exactly ¶5.1 -- our `const char*` isn't *compatible* with the RHS being `const char[6]`, or `const char* const` after *array to pointer* conversion.

For this exact reason, or lack thereof,  this can compiles error-free:

```
char* const & a = "hello";
```

*ISO C++11* warning aside, a compiler lets this one pass (not that it should, as the string literal is a 'const char [6](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.array)' and we shouldn't be dropping this first `const`), as the reference is now `const` with regards to its object, the pointer.

Another interesting thing is that An `rvalue` reference `const char* && a`  (no "2nd `const`") *could* bind to the temporary pointer that has materialized from the *string literal*, as @StoryTeller provided himself. Why is that? Because of the rules of [*array to pointer conversion*:](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.array)

> **An lvalue** or rvalue **of type "array of N T"** or "array of unknown bound
>   of T" **can be converted to a *prvalue* of type "pointer to T"**.

No mention of `const` or other *cv-qualification* phrasing in here, but this stands only as long as we're initializing an rvalue ref.